# Thanks page get 404 page error in wp-ecommerce plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This is my store url [Store](http://murphysbleachers.com/store/)
When i add product in cart then after i click on checkout then after purchase this product and then i can't see thanks page it goes to 404 page.

Because of in url added my ftp user name.

Comment: Could you please provide us the url of your thanks page and and the generated url.

Answer (score 0):

Checked you are using wp e commerce plugin. In this case your thank you page url should be:
domain/products-page/transaction-results/?sessionid=some id

Do one thing go to setting->permalink and resave the form. Be sure that htaccess file in write mode.